# Replace strings that contain random numbers from a file

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for code to replace effectively, a string which contains numbers. However, the numbers can be either or in-between `0.50` and `2.20` with increments of 2. So `0.50`, `0.52`, `0.62`.... etc

To explain it better, my program is replacing lines in a config (text) file. Here is an example of how I used it for other parts of my program. Since this is linked to a trackbar control, it would mean searching for hundreds of different values with the single selected value, which of course, is very inefficient. I am just looking for a more efficient way of replacing values. Here is a previous example which inserts one of 3 possible values:

```
ReWriteFile = ReWriteFile
   .Replace("  clipmapScale:r=0.5", "  clipmapScale:r=1.5")
   .Replace("  clipmapScale:r=1", "  clipmapScale:r=1.5");
```

This control had only 3 possible values (0.5, 1.0, 1.5), but my other control has 85 possible values.

If there was a way to grab numbers from a string and replace them and write them back. I'm not so fluent in C# as I've just started to learn it (Uni student here).

Maybe catching it as a string with specified characters like [0-9,.,].

Comment: It is not clear what is the rule for replacing. You want to replace every existing number with a predefined value? (0.5 or 1 become both 1.5) Or there is a different rule?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it very well. I wanted to replace any value in the format `@"\d+\.\d+";` that you listed below. The value I want to replace it with is received from the .Value property of a trackbar.
I have this at the moment:
`string SelectedValue = trkTerrainQualityVal.Value.ToString();
           string pattern = @"\d+\.\d+";
            string search = "  clipmapScale:r=";
            var m = Regex.Replace(search, pattern, SelectedValue);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to replace every decimal number inside a string with a new number (no calculation on the found value) then it is a simple Regex expression and just one call to Replace

```
string newValue = "1.5";
// Matches any number followed by a dot and then another number
string pattern = @"\d+\.\d+";
string search = "..... clipmapScale:r=0.5 clipmapScale:r=1.0 .....";
var m = Regex.Replace(search, pattern, newValue);
Console.WriteLine(m);
```

Of course, if you want to restrict the matched parts to only the numbers after the *clipmapScale* text you can change to

```
string newValue = "clipmapScale:r=1.5";
string pattern = @"clipmapScale:r=\d+\.\d+";
```

Comment: Yes, I understand this now, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Regular Expression` for that purpose. Imagine you want to replace all decimal numbers with `#` characters. You can use the following code snippets for that.

```
        string input = "this0.4is7.8some0.89input";
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+\.\d+");
        var s =regex.Replace(input, "#");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```